# JUnit 5 tests are executed in parallel inside IntelliJ and locally with Maven, but not inside Maven Docker container on Google Cloud Build

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, junit5, google-cloud-build

I am using JUnit 5 in my Maven project.

My `junit-platform.properties` looks like this:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent
```

When running the tests inside IntelliJ or with Maven locally, the test are executed in parallel.

However, when running them on Cloud Build inside a Maven Docker container, they seem to run sequentially.

This is how they are called:

```
steps:
  - name: 'maven:3-jdk-11-slim'
    args: [
      'mvn',
      # https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513809/3067148
      '-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true',
      '-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat=HH:mm:ss,SSS',
      '-B',
      'test'
    ]
```

What could be the reason why they aren't executed in parallel?

Comment: How many processors/cores are usable on your "Cloud Build inside a Maven Docker container" setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Properties such as the desired parallelism and the maximum pool size can be configured using a `ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy`. The JUnit Platform provides two implementations out of the box: `dynamic` and `fixed`. Alternatively, you may implement a custom strategy.

Keep in mind that the [ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/support/hierarchical/ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy.html#createConfiguration(org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters)) class is still in the "EXPERIMENTAL" state and it is not yet stable. Unintended behaviour may occur.

As you don't set a specific configuration strategy, the following section applies:

> If no configuration strategy is set, JUnit Jupiter uses the `dynamic` configuration strategy with a factor of 1. Consequently, the desired parallelism will be equal to the number of available processors/cores.

Find more details at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution-config

Comment: In version 5.10.0 "the dynamic parallel execution strategy now allows the thread pool to be saturated by default." So factor of 1 property no longer necessary?